# How do I put the donate button on the left and the paragraph of text on the right?

Tags: css, wordpress

Firstly, I understand this is an easy question to answer for those of you who know CSS very well. I am a guy with basic web development skills and I am helping a new charity by building their website. So, please forgive me for asking an "easy" question that Google could help with. The problem is that I can't understand how to fix this with my theme. Googling basic CSS questions won't help me with this specific problem. Thanks.

On this page: http://www.ukraineaid.org/who/

I want to put the donate button on the left and the paragraph of text on the right? I have tried to edit the Danko wordpress theme to achieve this but something is messing it up. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in `css`:

```
.home-button {
width: 361px;
height: 84px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 21px;
}
```

and

```
.home-money {
width: 560px;
float: right;
}
```

[image: **preview**]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `margin-right: 20px;` from the `.home-button` class should work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to following class and add **float:right;** and remove **.left** class

[image]

```
.home-money {
width: 560px;
float: right;
}
```

And to following class add float:left;

```
.home-button a {
float: left;
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: It is because you have not added float:right to .home-money. Check it using developer tool

Comment: Try reloading you browser , or try in different browser. Css changes might not be loaded properly

Comment: Tried a different browser. Same problem. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah it does. Seethe screenshot attached above.  Try adding !important after float:right;

Comment: Did that. Still not displaying properly.

Comment: You are missing something. It worked for me in no time

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Change class `.left` to `.right` in `.home-money` div
- reduce the width of `.home-button` from 400px to 380px if you want have a margin-right of 20px **OR** remove margin-right i.e. `margin-right: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can change the following css to set your design

```
.home-button {
    height: 84px;

    width: 400px;
}


.home-money {
    float: right !important;
    width: 560px;
}
```